# Including text with <strong> and <em> tags when scraping html using lxml & requests?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm scraping text from a webpage using lxml and requests. All of the text that I want is under `<p>` tags. When I use `contents = tree.xpath('//*[@id="storytext"]/p/text()')`, `contents` only includes text that is not in `<em>` or `<strong>` tags. But when I use `contents = tree.xpath('//*[@id="storytext"]/p/text() | //*[@id="storytext"]/p/strong/text() | //*[@id="storytext"]/p/em/text()')`, the text in `<em>` and `<strong>` tabs is separated from the rest of the text in that `<p>` tag.

I would like to:

1. scrape each `<p>` as a unit, including all its text (whether plain or `<em>` or `<strong>`), and
2. keep the `<em>` and `<strong>` tags so that I can use them later to format the text I've scraped.

**Sample html:**
`<div id="storytext"><p>"Go <em>away!</em>" His voice was drowned out by the mixer. She didn't even <em>hear</em> him. He could scrub it all day, probably, and Esti would just say <em>can't you do anything</em>? He scowled fiercely at the dirt.</p></div>`

**Desired output:**
`"Go <em>away!</em>" His voice was drowned out by the mixer. She didn't even <em>hear</em> him. He could scrub it all day, probably, and Esti would just say <em>can't you do anything</em>? He scowled fiercely at the dirt.`

Comment: Just iterate the `p`'s and use `./strong/text()` or `./em/text()`

Comment: could you include sample html  with expected result?

Comment: @QHarr: updated!

Comment: @pguardiario: could you post an answer explaining that approach more fully?

Comment: Are there only strong and em tags within actual html between p tags?

Comment: yes, only those tags

Answer (score 0):

If only those between you could use bs4 and `replace` to remove the p open and close tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div id="storytext"><p>"Go <em>away!</em>" His voice was drowned out by the mixer. She didn't even <em>hear</em> him. He could scrub it all day, probably, and Esti would just say <em>can't you do anything</em>? He scowled fiercely at the dirt.</p></div>
'''

soup = bs(html,'lxml')

for item in soup.select('p'):
    print(str(item).replace('<p>','').replace('</p>',''))
```

---

Using `requests` to source html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('url')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('p'):
    print(str(item).replace('<p>','').replace('</p>',''))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to combine that with the xpath query I'm using (see first part of my question)?

Comment: I don’t think you need xpath. If you feed your html to beautiful soup it will print as blocks of p tags with those other tags still in

Comment: The for loop will allow for printing each as a block

Comment: Ooh cool. I was previously accessing the html via url; how would I do that using beautiful soup?